# Adding many buttons to header in JQuery Mobile

Tags: header, jquery-mobile

I know that we can add left and right buttons in a header in Jquery Mobile App.

But can we any more buttons or controls in the header section itself?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think I have a better solution,

```
<header data-role ="header" data-theme="b"> 
  <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">Staff</h1>
    <div class="ui-btn-right" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
     <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">filter</a>
      <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">move</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Screenshot;

[image]

Comment: you can also just add a div: <div class="ui-btn-right">...a elements here </div> !

Answer (score 7):

with regard to this info:
[image: Device Widths]
you can find it here:
http://www.metaltoad.com/sites/default/files/Responsive-Widths_0.png

[image: multiple buttons jquery mobile header]
you can use this code:

```
   <style type="text/css">              
    @media all{
        .my-header-grid.ui-grid-b .ui-block-a { width: 30%; }
        .my-header-grid.ui-grid-b .ui-block-b { width: 40%; }
        .my-header-grid.ui-grid-b .ui-block-c { width: 30%; }
        }
    }       
    </style>
    <div class="my-header-grid ui-grid-b" data-theme="a">
        <div class="ui-block-a ui-bar-a" data-theme="a">
            <div align="left" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:3px;height:33px;height:40px;">
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn-left" rel="external" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-theme="a">Back</a>
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b ui-bar-a">
            <div align="center" style="padding-top:3px;height:33px;text-align:center;height:40px;">
            <div style="padding-top:7px;">
                <article role="heading" aria-level="1">expand </article>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-c ui-bar-a">
            <div align="right" style="padding-top:3px;height:33px;height:40px;">
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn-left" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right" rel="external" data-mini="true" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" data-theme="a">Refresh</a>                          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /grid-b -->
```

if by any chance your programming with c# mvc razor engine don't forget to write the css media tag with 2 @ like so @@media because the razor engine treats 2 @ as one.

you see and can play with all of the designs shown here in this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/BAat8/

---

iv added some links but i recommend youll read this:
http://appcropolis.com/blog/advanced-customization-jquery-mobile-buttons/

the simple implantation is:

```
    <header data-role ="header" data-theme="a"> 
        <a data-icon="back" href="/" rel="external">Back</a>
        <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">Staff</h1>
        <a class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="back" href="#" rel="external">Refresh</a>
    </header>
```

or this:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a data-icon="back" href="/" rel="external">Back</a>
        <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">Staff</h1>
        <div class="ui-btn-right" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">          
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">filter</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">move</a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

or this:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <div class="ui-btn-left" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">filter</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">move</a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">Staff</h1>
        <div class="ui-btn-right" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear">filter</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">move</a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

hope iv helped.

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier to create a custom navbar instead of modifying the header toolbar, Here si the docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

```
<div class="ui-btn-right">
    <!-- Home Button -->
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" 
       data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" data-corners="true" 
       data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="b" title="Refresh">
    </a>
    <!-- Home Button -->
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" 
       data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" data-corners="true" 
       data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="b" title="Home">
    </a>
</div>
```

This gives me those nice rounded buttons, two side by side on the right side.

Just like on the mobile docs.

Works in 1.1.1, haven't tried the latest RC

Comment: Sorry about the comments Home Button, Home Button, just copied my home button twice and changed the icon.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by the following code:

```
<div data-role ="header" data-theme="b"> 
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-left" id="BackButtonHandler">Prev</a>
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="margin-left:75px;margin-top:5px;" >
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" >P.Week</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">N.Week</a>
    </div>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-right" id="BackButtonHandler">Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is a hard limit of 2 as far as I have found.  The best I was able to come up with was to get another unstyled link to appear.

There are however, navbars - On one of my projects, I needed a number of buttons in the header area, I placed a navbar directly below it, and was reasonable pleased with the results.

They are explained in detail here:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html