# Listview checkbox and anchor tag to behave differently jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I want a listview which behave differently on clicking anchor tag and checkbox.

Simply add check box at right side of listview and make it behave independent of anchor tag.

```
<ul  data-role="listview">
  <li> <a href="#">link</a>
    <label>
      <input name="checkbox-0" data-inline="true" id="checkbox-0" type="checkbox" data-role="none" />
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/manojbojja/b3y99xae/

Comment: please provide link or fiddle, show your attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <li><a href="#" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;">
            <label style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;" data-corners="false">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" style="height:0px !important">
                    <input id="checkbox_11" name="checkbox_11" class="item_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="false"/>
                        <label>
                            <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5490/10815278466_fb2b758e01_s.jpg" style="height:60px;width:60px;float:left;padding-right:10px;"/>
                            <h2 style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px">11</h2>
                            <p>11/12/2013 10:16:14 AM</p>
                        </label>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
            </label>
            </a><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250969/adding-many-buttons-to-header-in-jquery-mobile" rel="external"></a>
        </li>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/PBQ3P/)