# jQuery multiple buttons in header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add 3 buttons to the header of a mobile web-app i am making with jQuery.

I am able to make 2 buttons but as soon as i put the 3rd on the header the first dissapears :/

i tried the answer in this question: [Adding many buttons to header in JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250969/adding-many-buttons-to-header-in-jquery-mobile)

however for some reason jquery style's will not apply to div tags inside the header.

my header currently has this code:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <div class="ui-btn-left" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#" id="homebtn" data-roll="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <a href="#" id="searchbtn" data-roll="button" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left"></a>
    </div>
        <h1 id="usr"></h1>
    <a href="#" id="profileButton" data-roll="button" data-icon="info">Profile</a>  

    </div>
```

and my webpage looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody have any ideas why this is happening?

**please excuse any grammar/spelling mistakes: I am dyslexic and may have missed some in proof reading**

Comment: It probably has to do with the ui-btn-left class.  Try using Inspect Element in your browser to play with the CSS.

Comment: Did you really want to type 'data-roll="button"' (DATA-ROLL), not 'data-role="button"'?

Comment: umm, yes, yes i did..... i'll fix that now xD..... and i will try playing with the CSS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

okay so thanks to @TSV who pointed out i was using "data-roll" not "data-role"

that actually fixed my problem completely :)